# R: Fastest way to residualize hundreds of variables

Tags: r, data.table, regression, lapply

I have a large data set (~30m observations, ~800 variables) and I need to residualize 700 variables by regressing each of them on 3 variables and then storing the residuals. Here is what I am currently doing:

```
io_d[, (vars_to_residualize_list) := lapply(.SD, 
        function(X) {lm(X ~ X1 + X2 + X3)$residuals}),
        .SDcols = vars_to_residualize]
```

Where `vars_to_residualize` is a list of the variables to residualize and `vars_to_residualize_list` is a list of the new names for the residuals.

This takes about 70 hours to get through all the variables.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Are `X1`, `X2` and `X3` all continuous? Dense? You should definitely parallelize across the `700` variables. You can also skip down a level and use `lm.fit` directly instead of creating the whole `lm` object. Read the source code of `lm` a bit to get an idea on this.

Comment: They are all factors. Parallelizing is a good idea. I will look into `lm.fit`.

Comment: if `X1`, `X2`, and `X3` are all factors, you're not really regressing on 3 variables, you're regressing on `n1 -1 + n2 - 1 + n3 - 1` variables where `nk` is the number of levels of `Xk`. The upside is that this regression is likely massively sparse and you can use `sparse.model.matrix` & sparse regression methods will likely be a lot faster. If you're careful about your matrix algebra/regression techniques you may not even need to compute the design matrix at all.

Comment: One last thing -- if `X1`:`X3` are _always the same_ across your 700 regressions, you should use `model.matrix` or `sparse.model.matrix` _only once` to create and store your design matrix. No need to bother creating this object 700 different times if it's a repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you reduce times, significantly [fastLm() is much slower than lm()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420185/fastlm-is-much-slower-than-lm); slightly modify the code of `fLmSEXP` to be able to extract the residuals.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(rbenchmark)
## start from SEXP, most conversions, longest code
src <- '
Rcpp::List fLmSEXP(SEXP Xs, SEXP ys) {
Rcpp::NumericMatrix Xr(Xs);
Rcpp::NumericVector yr(ys);
int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);
arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);
// fit model y ~ X, extract residuals
arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);
arma::colvec res  = y - X*coef;
// return the results
return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("coefficients")=coef,Rcpp::Named("res")=res);
}
'
cppFunction(code=src, depends="RcppArmadillo")
```

I create my data frame

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:4,300000,rep=TRUE)))
df = cbind(X = rnorm(300000),df)
head(df)
           X X1 X2 X3
1  0.6269854  1  4  3
2  0.4641201  1  1  4
3 -0.5625020  3  1  4
4  0.0452215  2  1  2
5  2.2453335  3  3  2
6  0.4045328  1  3  3
m <- as.matrix(cbind(X = df[,1],cbind(I = 1,df[,2:4])))
```

I compare the results of both functions

```
benchmark(
lm_res = lm(X ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = df)$residuals,
flm_res = fLmSEXP(m[,2:5],m[,1])$res, replications = 100)[,1:4]

    test replications elapsed relative
2 flm_res          100    4.14    1.00
1  lm_res          100   12.46    3.01
```

I hope this will be helpful, or at least give you a way.

Comment: Looks interesting - I will give it a try!