# R: Performance of running Linear Regressions with lm() vs. calculating with matrix operations vs. using QR decomposition

Tags: r, performance, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I have been running linear regressions lately to replicate the results shown in journal articles. In many cases, there are 5 to 15 regressors for which I need to find estimates in form of beta coefficients and the data sets are relatively speaking huge: 5E+05 to 5E+07 rows and 5 to 15 columns.

Now the "issue" is the time consumption of these and similar regressions. So what I did, was that I ran the regressions through different methods of using the R's existing methods and linear algrebraic solutions. I tested the methods on random data generated by R since I do not care about t-values or anything like that, I only care about the point estimates.

The methods I used were

1. The stock method that calculates other results as well, like t-values, residual standard errors etc.

> `lm()`

2. The direct linear algebraic matrix multiplication with INVERSE required

> `point_estimates <- solve(t(A) %*% A) %*% t(A) %*% y`

3. The method involving QR decomposition:

> `point_estimates <- qr.solve(A, y)`

4. The R's stats packages method `lm.fit()` which I think is also QR decomposition based:

> `point_estimates <- lm.fit(A, y)$coefficients`

The matrix A has its first column only values 1, since that way getting the intercept of constant term is ensured for other methods than `lm()` as well.

My setup is Windows R which using the Microsoft Open R optimized for Intel processors so I can use the Intel MKL software to speedup matrix calculations.

Guess, which one of the methods was the fastest?

The results were consistently

1. Direct linear algebra method, speed 100%
2. `lm.fit()`, speed 107%
3. QR decomposition -method, speed 124%
4. `lm()` (unsuprising, since this method calculates also other things than just the point estimates),  speed 190%

The speeds in percentages are w.r.t to the fastest method and are just ballpark values, not too exact since they vary between runs. Now my questions are:

1. Why causes these differences between the three fastest methods?
2. Why the direct linear algebra method is so quick despite there being the inverse calculation? I know that the inverses are not always computable if the matrices columns are not linearly independent *enough*, so matrix A'A must not be singular for the computation to be possible and stable. One reason causing these issues is multicolinearity between the regressors.
3. To address the possible issue in the previous question, one would use the methods involving QR decompositions, but why is `lm.fit()` so much and consistently faster compared to `qr.solve()` despite they essentially do the same things?
4. If one only cares about the point estimates and for sure knows that there is now multicolinearity in the data matrix A, why would one opt for using the QR methods, if the pure linear algebraic method is the fastest one?
5. Are there any faster ways to get point estimates of regressor coefficients in R? Also regression solutions applicable for fixed effects linear regression models are welcome.

Disclaimer: I do know that all the mehtods I mentioned use linear algebra and matrices and I do know how they work, I even had to do couple by hand at the university when I was studying mathematics.

Comment: If you only need the coefficients then flm in the collapse package is fast.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Does collapse package also contain methods for fixed-effects linear regressions? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The last example in [`?lm.fit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lmfit.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I actually used microbencmark to run the tests, but I will also create the boxplots to get an idea of the time distributions.

Comment: flm uses fixed effects like lm.  Look at the help page.

Comment: For me, `solve(t(A) %*% A) %*% t(A) %*% y` is about 2.5 times slower than `solve(crossprod(A)) %*% crossprod(A, y)` with 15 variables and `5e6` rows.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Thanks, I will check that crossproduct solution as well. Fairly interesting that my linear algebra books didn't mention crossproducts as possible solution for deriving the regressors' estimates, yet it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I posted an answer below to show the new results I got with your methdos included to previous ones.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423825/190277

Comment: @BenBolker Please see the edit I made my to answer below. I got the MRO working. The post you refer, got the relative difference to be 120.7% between its fastest method fLmSEXP() and lm.fit(). I used lm.fit() as well, but with the MRO, the difference between the fastest method Crossproduct and lm.fit() on my setup turned out to be 129%. I know the sample sizes (referred post 5000 vs 200 by me) and setups are most likely different, but at least the Crossproduct method is in the same ballpark execution time-wise as the fLmSEXP() from RCppArmadillo, if not the Crossproduct being even faster.

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't dug into this. I think your question is good; it would be nice to think also about the *theoretical* computational complexity of each of these methods ...)

Comment: I keep forgetting _what_ the trick was but I think years after I wrote `fastLm()` (which is fast and gets you `\hat{\beta}` and their stderrors (which `lm.fit()` does not) Martin Maechler posted an equally fast but not exported / documented shortcut using some unexported base R function.  And you still repeating the no-longer-true-for-many-years now trope that MRO is needed for MKL.  You get MKL 'for free' for Ubuntu too, directly in the distro. And Linux tends to run circles around Wiindows so something to consider.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have been using Ubuntu for Python programming, but I'll also transfer to Ubuntu for R as well, sooner or later, so I will then see how to also get the MKL for Ubuntu. The stderrors would also quite useful, since the t-values for individual point-estimates of betas will become useful later on. So finding the fastest possible way to get 1) point-estimates 2) stderrors(/t-values) for regressors would be useful as well.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, I was actually wondering, am I asking too elementary questions. As an applied mathematics/statistics/econometrics person, I do not know really anything about the computational complexity other than what I have done tasks on paper. The real question then would be, how exactly the computer does these calculations and allocates memory during the process etc. I guess, that in some cases (trading in the stock market) even the accuracy of the point-estimates could be sacrificed, to certain extent, in the pursuit of absolute speed of getting the estimates out.

Comment: I don't think these are too elementary. The only reason I mentioned computational complexity is that it would give a hint as to whether the timing constraints were due to intrinsic computational complexity or to something about the implementation surrounding the basic operations.

Comment: @BenBolker For smaller samples, when there are maybe 500 rows of data, the Crossproduct method and direct LA method, turned out be the slowest, previously they were the fastest for large sample with 5E+06 rows. So there definitely is some underlying O(of something) to cause the differences in the computation times. At least, on really small samples logarithmically speaking, the differences get smaller and smaller. Would be wonderful to speak about these issues with some expert one day.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering a little bit about one of the unspoken premises of this question, which is that we need to worry a lot about speed for a linear regression in R with 5e6 observations and 15 columns on modern hardware. So far with my experiments for `n = 5e6`, `p = 15`), the *slowest* method (`lm()`) takes about 2.5 seconds per fit, so unless you need to do *lots* of regressions, it's hard to see this being a big bottleneck in your workflow.

My results are consistent with `crossprod + solve` and Cholesky-based methods being fastest (0.25 seconds/fit).

This is on a machine with a reasonably amount of memory (68 Gb). I tried setting the number of BLAS threads differently, but I don't think I got the incantation right - the results for 1, 4, and 16 (nominal) threads were all about the same ...

```
R Under development (unstable) (2023-05-01 r84362)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so;  LAPACK version 3.10.0
```

```r
 > bb01
              test elapsed relative user.self sys.self
8    collapse_chol   6.310    1.000     6.309    0.000
11 collapse_eigen2   6.412    1.016     6.363    0.048
12 collapse_eigen3   6.436    1.020     6.395    0.040
5   collapse_solve   6.486    1.028     6.486    0.001
14 collapse_eigen5  13.845    2.194    12.244    1.601
10 collapse_eigen1  28.789    4.562    27.217    1.569
3            solve  30.757    4.874    20.064   10.690
9  collapse_eigen0  31.062    4.923    29.460    1.601
7    collapse_arma  32.942    5.221    32.929    0.009
4      collapse_lm  39.589    6.274    35.751    3.832
2            lmfit  40.975    6.494    36.890    4.074
6      collapse_qr  46.689    7.399    30.480   16.201
1               lm  66.504   10.539    53.042   13.454
13 collapse_eigen4 180.576   28.617   165.031   15.529
```

`eigen` methods:

```
0 column-pivoted QR decomposition.                                 
1 unpivoted QR decomposition.                                      
2 LLT Cholesky.                                                    
3 LDLT Cholesky.                                                   
4 Jacobi singular value decomposition (SVD).                       
5 method based on the eigenvalue-eigenvector decomposition of X'X.
```

---

```r
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(rbenchmark)
library(collapse)
library(RhpcBLASctl)
benchfun <- function(n = 5e6, p = 15, blas_threads = 1, reps = 25, seed= 101) {
    blas_set_num_threads(blas_threads)
    set.seed(seed)
    X <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), ncol = p,
                dimnames = list(NULL, sprintf("p%d", seq(p))))
    y <- matrix(rnorm(n))
    dd <- data.frame(X, y)
    bb <- benchmark(lm = lm(y ~ . + 0, dd),
                    lmfit = lm.fit(X, y),
                    solve = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y,
                    collapse_lm = flm(y, X, method = "lm"), ## .lm.fit
                    collapse_solve = flm(y, X, method = "solve"), ## crossprod-solve
                    collapse_qr = flm(y, X, method = "qr"),  ## qr.coef(qr(X), y)
                    collapse_arma = flm(y, X, method = "arma"), ## RcppArmadillo::fastLmPure
                    collapse_chol = flm(y, X, method = "chol"),
                    collapse_eigen0 = flm(y, X, method = "eigen", eigen.method = 0),
                    collapse_eigen1 = flm(y, X, method = "eigen", eigen.method = 1),
                    collapse_eigen2 = flm(y, X, method = "eigen", eigen.method = 2),
                    collapse_eigen3 = flm(y, X, method = "eigen", eigen.method = 3),
                    collapse_eigen4 = flm(y, X, method = "eigen", eigen.method = 4),
                    collapse_eigen5 = flm(y, X, method = "eigen", eigen.method = 5),
                    replications = reps)
    bb[order(bb$elapsed), c("test", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self", "sys.self")]                
}

bb16 <- benchfun(blas_threads = 16)
bb04 <- benchfun(blas_threads = 4)
bb01 <- benchfun(blas_threads = 1)
```

Comment: Nice to see that my results weren't flukes but actually reproducable even on different equipment and setups. Awesome that you created all the different eigen methods, but some of them do have limitations. For example, doesn't the Cholesky LL' decomposition require the orignial matrix to be positive definite square matrice? The square matrix is easy to form, but is the resulting X'X for sure positive definite? Comment on unspoken premise: I may run even thousands of these regressions to generate "rolling" beta coefficients on timeseries. Trading stocks/options needs fast calculations as well.

Comment: Adding to previous comment: The X'X is positive definite, IF X itself is fullrank. And ofcourse X is fullrank, when the column vectors (regressors' data) are linearly independent, i.e. no multicolinearity is present in the data. Funny how the multicolinearity always finds its way to every possible situation when the betas, regressors' point estimates, are to be calculated.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add new findings after I got the inputs from @G. Grothendieck and @DaveArmstrong. I did the same tests as in the original post with new proposed methods to find the coefficients. NOTE: tests now done on stock R 4.3.0. Microsoft Open R (MRO) didn't recognize the `collapse` package required for `flm`

Ran the regressions with 5E+06 rows and 8 columns with the methdos being

1. Stock R's linear regression method: `point_estimates <- lm()$coefficients`
2. Linear algebra mehtod: `point_estimates <- solve(t(A) %*% A) %*% t(A) %*% y`
3. QR decompotion: `point_estimates <- qr.solve(A, y)`
4. lm.fit(): `point_estimates <- lm.fit(A, y)$coefficients`
5. Fast linear regression from `collapse` package: `point_estimates <-flm()$coefficients`
6. Crossproduct method: `point_estimates <- solve(crossprod(A)) %*% crossprod(A, y)`

The results: Once again the fastest has speed index of 100% and rest are scaled from that. So the order of these six mehtods turned out as

1. Crossproduct method, speed 100%
2. `flm()`, speed 195%
3. Direct linear algebra -method, speed 202%
4. `lm.fit()`, speed 210%
5. QR decomposotion -method, speed 215%
6. `lm()`, speed 305%

The order is most likely very persistent if more tests were to be run, but the magnitude speed differences would definitely vary.

I assume, that crossproduct and linear algebra methods have similar limitations induced by the invertability or lack of it, that is caused by linearly dependent vectors that in turn arise from multicolinearity of the regressors.

And once again, note that I wasn't able to utilize the Intel MKL library from MRO for these tests for some reason, so make out of that what you will considering the results.

EDIT:
I got the MRO (along come the important Intel MKL packages) working and ran the same tests for the 5 fastest methods. Everything got faster by 3% to 30%. The new order looks like following with relative execution times:

1. Crossproduct method, speed 100%
2. Direct linear algebra -method, speed 189%
3. `flm()`, speed 191%
4. `lm.fit()`, speed 229%
5. QR decomposition -method, speed 272%

Despite the percentages increaed for the two methods that came last, they still got faster, but the crossproduct got even more faster. Also, interestingly the pure linear algebra method surpassed the fast linear regression, which didn't really gain from the Intel Matrix Kernel Library's fast execution methods.

So what to make out of this? If I firstly learn CPP well enough, then I will ofcourse look for those linear regression methods, but prior to that I will use the Crossproduct method if I am sure there's very little multicollinearity in the dataset so the regressor input values in matrix format are not linearly dependent and thus the matrix operations remain well-defined and resulting point-estimates robust.